# Secure username and password in Android

Tags: java, android, security, passwords

### Problem Description

I am writing application which must connect to the server and download some data from the server. The URL of the file witch must be downloaded is formatted as follow:

http://www.myserver.com/file.xml?username=xxx&password=xxx

### Question

URL and password **are not provided** by the user, I simply keep them in the code and add to the URL where I need. My question is **how can I keep securely password and username** on the Android device.

Comment: Just as a hint, this is a considerable security flaw. Even if you locally encrypt the content, any packet sniffer may see the data exchange - and capture the unencrypted URL in all its glory. Switching to HTTPS won't help, since the encryption will only kick in AFTER you identify the resource you want.

Comment: use  encryption and shared preference

Comment: So I must use Encrypted Key ?

Comment: Do you have any control over the code at 'myserver.com', or that URL format is mandatory?

Comment: Yes I have control over the server

Comment: Excellent. I'll post an implementation suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @OnoSendai I will wait ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against keeping any kind of credential (username) and authenticator (password) stored on your device, as well as transmitting them around; this is often considered a security flaw, since middle-man attacks can intercept the HTTP traffic and easily identify both.

I would recommend instead the creation a token engine that would associate temporary identifiers to users and devices. For example:

- User ID **100** receives a temporary token, code **A1S2D3F4** (randomly generated.)
- The code is associated with the device ID **AND200**.
- Whenever device AND200 tries to access the server, it would generate the following URL:

> http://www.myserver.com/file.xml?t=A1S2D3F4

Notice that there is no content identifying the user, nor its credentials or passwords. You may check if the device generating the URL is the one the token was originally associated with. Adittional controls may be implemented to detect tokens being used out of their lifespan, and help identify malicious users.

Comment: And from where server know that A1S2D3F4 is secure device ? and that server must provide information to that device ?

Comment: The idea is that the token A1S2D3F4 is associated with the device ID AND200 and User ID 100. You may store that information at the moment you generate the token, and retrieve it once the URL is used.

Comment: So server must no that A1S2D3F4 is associated with the device ID AND200 and User ID 100 ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can use Md5 encoding method for password encoding and if you need to save those  user details then it store in the shared preference

Comment: So you suggest to keep password Md5 encoded in the shared preferences ? and then decode it put in the URL and send ?

Comment: Please try to pass encoded password through Url i think that is better

Comment: Store something confidential in the device is not a good idea. If you encrypt the password you'll need to store the key on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see if you can use Google OAuth2: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html

If not, do not send user name and password in the URL but in a HTTPS POST and the correct way is using SOAP web services.

Comment: HTTP POST is as insecure as a GET, only not so human-readable. And please indulge me and elaborate on why a SOAP service is the 'correct' way.

Comment: I'm speaking about HTTPS POST, the POSTed message will be encrypted.

Comment: You're correct, i misread that part of your post. But the question about the SOAP service stands; what would be the justification to implement yet another layer? What obvious benefit would SOAP by itself bring to the process?

Comment: Ok if you don't want to implement a SOAP web service, you should implement the message layer yourself, it will be something like:

The client side HTTPS POSTs a message like:
username:the user name
password:the password
=> that message will be encrypted.
The server side should specifically analyse the client message.

Comment: IMHO 'want' is a word that have no place in process mapping. You mentioned that the 'correct' thing to do was to implement a SOAP. Now, you may implement it frequently and be quite comfortable to implement SOAP services whenever the need arises, but it's just a tool - and, as a tool, it isn't a 'one size fits all'. And the point still stands about transmitting credential/authenticator pairs: You can't assume that things like the TCP stack, reserved memory or network pipelines are unbreakable. Within acceptable margins, you can't allow a faulty process to compromise sensitive user data.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint there is a good talk on google io conference about security of android apps.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/events/io/2012/sessions/gooio2012/107/)

They don't cover secure server communication explicitly but give some hints about it and provide an encryption library to simplify any encryption tasks.